# which is better retrofit or volley?

Tags: android, jsoup, android-volley, retrofit

I am trying to implement a code which makes intial get/post request to fetch the data then using that data i m going to fetch download links with jsoup.

file are n't greater than 200 kbs

so which is better to do this task?
1)intial request
2)downloading files

Comment: It definitely depends on your application and what its intended to do. Hope the links below help you decide. Good Luck!

http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/volley-vs-retrofit---a-battle-royale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to chose between: Volley and Retrofit

If you are :

1. ***Making Requests*** then I would like to say though both frameworks are capable of the same outcome, Retrofit is capable of accomplishing this without customization.  However, if you are implementing multiple requests within your application, and I suspect you are, customization may be necessary within Retrofit. Though that could be the case, at the simplest level **Retrofit** has the easier solution.
2. ***Downloading Files***(Image): Being able to make file requests was a pretty large factor in the making of our decision.  Volley comes packaged with a loader specifically designed to download images for you.  Packaged along with the loader is a custom view called the NetworkImageView in which the developer only has to hand a URL and an ImageLoader to and Volley does the rest.  This view is specifically targeted to work well with list views and allow for automatic cancellation of requests when the images parent view is destroyed.  On the contrary, Retrofit does not easily support image downloads.  To accomplish what we are able to with Volley, one would be required to download and include another library in your project such as Picasso. So here **Volley** is a better solution.